# Animation does not trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I came to an issue when I try to trigger the event that must turn on the block moving animation, that i set as "move" in animator, it doesn't go to this state, but when I manually trigger it it works completly fine. You can check a screenshot of an animator and ask me to screenshot anything else to solve the problem.

```cs
public class BlockScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator blockanim;
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            blockanim.SetTrigger("move");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animator]

Comment: use Debug.Log under SetTrigger and make sure your collider code executes correctly.

Comment: You're using OnTriggerEnter. Make sure at least one of the objects that are colliding has a rigidbody (you can turn off gravity and anchor its positions if needed) and they both have a collider of some kind. Secondly, one of the colliders needs to be set to isTrigger. Only one.

Comment: I used Debug.Log under SetStrigger and it doesn't work. But it triggers in my another Debug.Log and it says "Trigger" but that specific one i typed and script above don't say anyting. I didn't add rigidBody and made it Kinematic and I set its boxcollider2D to is Trigger

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jRIQUhP here how i made it and console with 2 debug.Logs i already had and as you can see on Screenshots "MOVE" debug.Log doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was solved by myself here is what i changed in code and now it works completely fine I didn't notice that I used box collider 2D

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BlockScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator blockanim;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            blockanim.SetTrigger("move");
            Debug.Log("MOVE");
        }
    } 
}
```